# How does Monero protect users from inflation bugs if the blockchain can't be audited?

Tags: auditing, emission-curve

Many Monero critics use statements like:

> How does Monero protect users from inflation bugs if the blockchain can't be audited?

Supposedly there is a way to audit the Monero supply. I've never done it, I've only read that its possible and that other people have done it. But how does one do it in a step by step way?

Can someone make a post about this so we can just point to this answer every time someone brings it up? Annoying to see people post about this all the time with the same people trying to give an answer but not really actually giving it.

How do you audit monero coin supply step by step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The daemon command `print_coinbase_tx_sum` is useful for auditing the *supply* (sum of all coinbase transactions).

```
help print_coinbase_tx_sum

Command usage: 
  print_coinbase_tx_sum <start_height> [<block_count>]

Command description: 
  Print the sum of coinbase transactions.
```

You then verify, the amount obtained from above, is less than per the [Emission curve](https://www.getmonero.org/technical-specs/) allows for. Example code to get this value for a given height [here](https://gist.github.com/jtgrassie/a2861cbdf80490280b7acc6e098b07a1).

For anything else, you would have to audit the code (for bugs) and the math (for soundness).

Comment: can you do this on a pruned 25gb monero blockchain or do you need the full 70+gb version?

Comment: I've not personally tried but can't see why it wouldn't. Surely anyone *auditing* the blockchain would not want/need to use a pruned node though.

Answer (score 0):

`monero_inflation_checker` is an independent tool created in Python to verify there's no hidden injection through mining or transactions: https://github.com/DangerousFreedom1984/monero_inflation_checker